# Как посредством javascript организовать поиск

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Пишу скрипт для выборки по базам. Есть Поле для выборки, там содержаться числовые значения и нужно их отмечать галочками и передавать скрипту т.к их очень много нужно сделать внизу поиск, что бы он искал и подсвечивал значения! Вот пример:

[image]

Comment: нету больше предложений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если jQuery подключен, то римерно так:

```
$('input').keyup(function () { 
    var text_to_search = $(this).val(); 
    $('select option').each(function () { 
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(text_to_search) == -1) { 
            $(this).hide(); //$(this).css('display', 'none'); тоже можно 
        } 
        else { 
            $(this).show(); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Хотя бы примерно! За что нить мне зацепится и работать с этим(( Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм:
Перебираете пункты, те, которые не подходят под введенную маску, меняете им css свойство display на none.

Самый простой вариант)

Comment: а примерно не могли бы написать! Css мало использую!